# Problem with teleop_base stage tutorial, how to install 'joy' package?

Tags: ros, simulation, stageros, stage, teleop-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to make the teleop_base tutorial, the first one for the stage simulator. At the moment of compile it requires me to install the joy package. I've found it available [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joy) but I don't know how to install it. Could someone please give me a help telling me the best/easiest way to do this?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot and ROS-Electric.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11666/problem-with-teleop_base-stage-tutorial,-how-to-install-%27joy%27-package?/) by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2011-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For electic and ubuntu install:

`sudo apt-get install ros-electric-joystick-drivers`

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-10-25**:
Yes, I fixed the typo. I'm not sure, if there is oneiric support yet. It should work from lucid to natty.

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2011-10-24**:
Hi, I believe there is a little mistake "electric", but when I run the command "sudo apt-get install ros-electric-joystick-drivers" my PC just can't find it in the repositories... I don't know if this stack it's still suported in ROS-electric. Thnx for your help dornhege.